# Wordpress multisite with subdomain and directory simultaneously

Tags: multisite

I want to use Wordpress multisite with subdomain and directory simultaneously like

```
http://site1.wp.com
http://site2.wp.com
http://wp.com/site3
```

All of the sub sites will be using same database and code.
Is there any way to use subdomain and directory at the same time?

Comment: There is no official support, but [you're not the first to try](https://wordpress.org/ideas/topic/unified-subdomains-and-subdirectories) - [similar question here on WPSE](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/33221/1685).

Answer (score 1):

It can be done, I'm actually using it for my private multisite installation.

1. Install WP multisite and set it up in "subdirectory-mode"
2. Install and setup the [Domain Mapping plugin](https://premium.wpmudev.org/project/domain-mapping/) by WPMU
3. Create a subdomain and point it to your installation. Add this subdomain via the Domain Mapping plugin.

By default your new sub-sites are accessible in a subdirectory but if you apply step 3 it can be accessed via the subdomain as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for the plugin anymore. Domain mapping is native.

Once the site is created you can change the domain to anything you like. the base domain will still follow the intial configuration, but once created, you can change it easily.

https://wordpress.org/support/article/wordpress-multisite-domain-mapping/